# jsonp memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, webservice-client, webservices-client

So I've recently setup a chrome extension to refresh a page and call a jsonp web service I've written but there is a memory leak. I've searched all of the internet to find solutions and nothing seems to work. I've used the plain jQuery .ajax() call specifying "jsonp", I've used jquery-jsonp found at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/, and a slew of other methods...I cannot get the memory leak to disappear. Can someone point me to an example that does what I'm looking for or point me in the right direction? I just need to see a script constantly call a jsonp call and not leak memory.

when running my code there is no leaks until i reach this code:

```
$.jsonp({
                url: serviceUrl + "/AddPick?callback=?&" + jQuery.param(json),
                success: function (returned, textStatus) {
                    callback({ "d": returned.d, "pickCount": pickCount });
                }
            });
```

if i replace that code with: `callback({ "d": "1", "pickCount": pickCount });`
then the leak goes away.

Comment: Can you post your code? Or at least a general layout of what you're doing code-wise? Also, is the memory leak on the JavaScript side or the server side? Remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsonp memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464766/jsonp-memory-leak)

Comment: @Justin Niessner, @joelatdotzilla requested the other question be deleted and this one be used instead.

Comment: I've added a code snippet, when removed there is no longer a memory leak...

Comment: Did you try to `delete returned.d;delete returned`? If you did and it didn't work, than something in your callback might still be holding a reference to the data/object.

Comment: Can you show `callback`?

Answer (score 2):

If your code is structured like this:

```
function callback() {
  // (or similar, maybe with `setTimeout`)

  $.jsonp({
    url: serviceUrl + "/AddPick?callback=?&" + jQuery.param(json),
    success: function (returned, textStatus) {
      callback({ "d": returned.d, "pickCount": pickCount });
    }
  });
}
```

Then a new `success` function is being created *recursively*.  The call stack may look like this:

```
> callback
  > $.jsonp
    > NEW success
      > callback
        > $.jsonp
          > NEW success
            > ...
```

The growing stack, the new `success` functions being created at each iteration, and the entire context of the `success` functions themselves (which includes `returned`, `textStatus`, and `callback`'s context) eventually lead to objects which the runtime must keep track of but are basically unused.

An alternative is to have a helper function outside of the scope of `callback`:

```
function callCallback(returned, textStatus) {
  callback({ "d": returned.d, "pickCount": pickCount });
}

function callback() {
  // (or similar, maybe with `setTimeout`)

  $.jsonp({
    url: serviceUrl + "/AddPick?callback=?&" + jQuery.param(json),
    success: callCallback
  });
}
```

If needed, make the function private.  For example:

```
var callback = (function () {
  function callCallback(returned, textStatus) {
    callback({ "d": returned.d, "pickCount": pickCount });
  }

  function callback() {
    // (or similar, maybe with `setTimeout`)

    $.jsonp({
      url: serviceUrl + "/AddPick?callback=?&" + jQuery.param(json),
      success: callCallback
    });
  }

  return callback;
})();
```